# Why would a folder named APT keep getting its name changed in explorer to "Start Menu"?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a folder called APT which is in the path

e:\profiles\apt

However, although it's technically called APT, it keeps showing up under the name "Start Menu".

There is a group policy for a domain called APT which redirects all the application data, etc., to this location.  But it bugs me that the name keeps appearing as Start Menu.

Note: Although it appears in explorer as "Start Menu".  You can type in the location as "E:\profiles\APT" and that also shows up.  In fact "start menu" disappears and it temporarily shows up as "APT" but will revert as soon as you close the explorer window.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, I've seen this before, but never that persistant. If you browse to `\\machinename\e$\profiles` from another location, does it show up as `Start Menu` or as `apt`?

If it still shows up as `Start Menu` then it could be something inside the `desktop.ini` file inside the folder.

If it shows its correct name, it could be an issue I've seen occasionally where Windows will just mix up filenames when rendering the display.

Comment: There is actually a desktop.ini file located inside the APT folder.  The contents are: [.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21786

Comment: I assume that deleting the desktop.ini fixed the problem?

Comment: @Matt: Deleting the `LocalizedResourceName` line will remove Explorer's display renaming.

Comment: That would have worked, I just commented out the LocalizedResourcename setting