# Weird Windows Explorer behavior on Win2k3

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, explorer

Have a Windows Server 2003 machine, which hosts some redirected start menus for the users.  When browsing the share where the live, all the start menu folders show up as "Start Menu" rather than the dept code that should be there.  However, when you click in the address bar, the proper path will be revealed.

Any ideas what it going on here?

In case I haven't explained too clearly, I made some video that shows the behavior:

[Weird Windows Explorer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ91dkErHSs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's something to do with a desktop.ini messing things up:

After searching the interbits, stumbled onto something with the desktop.ini and there is a serverfault issue that might be similar:

[Why would a folder named APT keep getting its name changed in explorer to "Start Menu"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/108951/why-would-a-folder-named-apt-keep-getting-its-name-changed-in-explorer-to-start)

Comment: ding ding ding!  Winner!  Thanks for pointing me to the right place.  My search-fu phails.

Comment: Happy to help.  That was a strange one that I figured I'd run into soon enough - so I just had to research it.  :)